# SML requires C++14 support

Tags: arduino, avr, arduino-c++, boost-sml

I am starting out with Adruino and wanted to use the [boost sml library](https://github.com/boost-ext/sml/tree/master) on it. I downloaded the sml.hpp file and added it to arduino project using the library manager. But when i try to run the file I get the following **error message:**

```
error: #error "[Boost::ext].SML requires C++14 support (Clang-3.4+, GCC-5.1+, MSVC-2015+)"
 #error "[Boost::ext].SML requires C++14 support (Clang-3.4+, GCC-5.1+, MSVC-2015+)"
```

**My Arduino:**

```
{
    "board": "arduino:avr:micro",
    "programmer": "avrisp",
    "port": "/dev/ttyACM0",
    "output": "../build",
    "sketch": "test.ino",
    "intelliSenseGen": "global"
}
```

I am using avr-gcc (gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) so it should support c++14?)
I changed the version of c++ to 14 in the **c_cpp_properties.json**

```
 "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Arduino",
            "compilerPath": "home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-w",
                "-std=c++14",
                "-fpermissive",
                "-fno-exceptions",
                "-ffunction-sections",
                "-fdata-sections",
                "-fno-threadsafe-statics",
                "-Wno-error=narrowing"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino",
                "home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/variants/micro",
                "/home/Arduino/libraries/src",
                "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include",
                "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/include-fixed",
                "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/avr/include"
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [
                "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "defines": [
...
"__cplusplus=201402L", 
...
```

The error gets thrown in the sml.hpp file

```
#if (__cplusplus < 201305L && _MSC_VER < 1900)
#error "[Boost::ext].SML requires C++14 support (Clang-3.4+, GCC-5.1+, MSVC-2015+)" 
#else
```

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards

**Edit**

My tasks.json for avr-g++ :

```
"version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: avr-g++ build active file",
            "command": "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-w",
                "-std=c++14",
                "-fpermissive",
                "-fno-exceptions",
                "-ffunction-sections",
                "-fdata-sections",
                "-fno-threadsafe-statics",
                "-Wno-error=narrowing"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does c_cpp_properties.json specify the behaviour of Intellisense or the compiler? I can't remember. You'll likely have to make a similar change in tasks.json either way.

Comment: Yes c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense, it has nothing to do with the compiler. Tasks.json is the file to change.

Comment: How are you building the code? You need to change the build configuration, not the intellisense configuration

Comment: I added the tasks.json for avr-g++ to initial post

Comment: How do you build the project?

Comment: The [tag:sml] tag is NOT for Boost.sml.  When adding tags you have to at least hover and read the first sentence of tag excerpt.

Comment: I am using vscode. I used the arduino: verify or upload button

Comment: How do you build the project?

Comment: What do you mean specifically?

Comment: I am using the vscode Arduino extension by microsoft

Comment: What exactly do you do to build the project? How do you configure the VSCode Arduino extension? Do you have a link to this extension?

Comment: The extension: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino all configuration i did is in the arduino.json above

Comment: And why do you ignore the other questions?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer it. The extension does the build for me

Comment: It looks like the extension doesn't support changing the C++ standard. I can't find an option for it.

Comment: where do you see that?

Comment: I opened your link and checked the options.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the option. I found the build preferences:
I added following flag to the arduino.json:

```
{
"board": "arduino:avr:micro",
"programmer": "avrisp",
"port": "/dev/ttyACM0",
"output": "../build",
"sketch": "test.ino",
"intelliSenseGen": "global",
"buildPreferences": [
    ["build.extra_flags", "-std=c++14"]
]
```